# How to use DocuSign with Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, docusignapi

I am using Next.js 13 and trying to set up the server within the framework.

I have the below file with `src/app/api/docusign`

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

import docusign from 'docusign-esign';

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  console.log("here")
  const dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();

  return NextResponse.json({ dsApiClient })
}
```

```
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/api/docusign/route.ts
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- error ./node_modules/docusign-esign/src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ApiClient'
Did you mean './ApiClient'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directorie
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
```

Comment: Try to add this line:

const docusign = require("docusign-esign");

Comment: Also, how do you build/get all packages with Next.js? with Node.js you would do "npm install" there has to be something similar where all packages are downloaded

Comment: So, did you run "npm install" ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @InbarGazit unfortunately none of them have worked.

Comment: By that you mean you get the same error? "Module not found: Can't resolve 'ApiClient'"

Comment: do you have a package.json file?

Comment: Does it have a line like this:
    "docusign-esign": "^6.2.0",

Comment: @InbarGazit Yes I am getting the same error"Module not found: Can't resolve 'ApiClient'. I have "docusign-esign": "^6.2.0" within the package.json file. I am also following the Next.js 13 docs found here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js is a server-based framework that can use server-side rendering, client-side (via React), or static rendering. (I'm new to Next.js, I just researched it a bit to answer your question.)

To add DocuSign to your Next.js app, read the documentation on [calling an external API with Next.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=nextjs+calling+external+api).

Note that you have two options for calling the DocuSign eSign API:

1. Use the DocuSign Node.js SDK
2. Call the API directly

I recommend that you call the API directly since the marshalling/unmarshalling of JSON objects is so easy in JavaScript.

Here are [several live examples](https://codepen.io/collection/RzQPKB) for using the eSign API from JavaScript. (Note that your app should use Authorization Code grant for authentication.)

```
The CodePen examples call the 
DocuSign eSign API directly--
no SDK is used. 
This "code" is required by StackOverflow when
the answer includes a link to CodePen.
Sigh
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue on Github: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-node-client/issues/232

Looks like it has to do with how webpack resolves the module. I wasn't able to get his solution to work however.